# Concentration of ammonium phosphate if dissolved in water

Tags: stoichiometry, units

> If $\pu{2.54 mg}$ of ammonium phosphate is dissolved in enough water to make $\pu{300 mL}$ of the solution, what is the molar concentration of the solution?

The answer is $\pu{5.68e-5 mol L-1}$. However, the answer I got using dimensional analysis was wrong:

$$\frac{\pu{0.254g} \ \ce{(NH4)3PO4}}{1} \times \frac{\pu{1 mol} \ \ce{(NH4)3PO4}}{\pu{144g} \ \ce{(NH4)3PO4}} \times \frac{1}{\pu{300L}} = \frac{\pu{0.00587mol} \ \ce{(NH4)3PO4}}{\mathrm L}$$

Could someone explain how they got this answer?

Comment: Please do read this section: [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)

Comment: Dimensional analysis? There's nothing to be analyzed. Most basic math is sufficient to solve this "problem".

Comment: Is there actually ammonium phosphate? It should lose ammonia as phosphate ion is a stronger base than $\ce{NH_3}$.

Comment: You missed the decimal point in $\pu{2.54 mg}$, mistaking it for $\pu{254 mg}$.

Comment: $2.54\pu{mg}=2.54\dot10^-3\pu{g}$. Also, $300$mL is different from $300$L. Also, the molar mass of ammonium phosphate is 149g.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, ammonium phosphate formula is $\ce{(NH4)3PO4}$. Second, I would recommend to write down an expression first, and only plug in the numbers at the end. Third, mind the [metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix): $\pu{1 mg} \neq \pu{10^{-1} g}$. That's said, and taking into account correct molecular weight of ammonium phosphate $M(\ce{(NH4)3PO4}) = \pu{149.09 g mol-1}$:

$$C = \frac{n}{V} = \frac{m}{MV} = \frac{\pu{2.54e-3 g}}{\pu{149.09 g mol-1} \cdot \pu{0.3 L}} = \pu{5.68e-5 mol L-1}$$

where $C$ – molar concentration, $n$ – amount, $V$ – volume, $m$ – mass.